# KivMob isn't loading ads

Tags: python, admob, kivy

Below is a "Hello World" code snippet that I reworked from KivMob examples on GitHub. The examples weren't really helpful because they lacked proper comments, so I didn't know what was going on.

I can't see any ads when I port this app to Android. I'm also failing to see the logic of how and where the ads are supposed to appear. Can someone please help me to get KivMob to show up on Android?

```
from kivmob import KivMob
import kivy.utils
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label

if platform not in ('android', 'ios'):
    # Approximate dimensions of mobile phone.
    Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')

__version__ = "1.0"

Builder.load_string("""
#:import kivy kivy
<KivMobDemoUI>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        AnchorLayout:
            CustomButton:
                text: "Toggle Banner"
                size_hint: 0.8, 0.2
                on_release: app.toggle_banner()
<CustomButton>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.box_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
    bold: True
    text_size: self.width, None
    height: self.texture_size[1]+size_hint_y: None
    text_size: self.width, None
    height: self.texture_size[1] + sp(20)
    halign: 'center'
    valign: 'middle'
""")


class KivMobDemoUI(FloatLayout):
    pass


class CustomButton(ButtonBehavior, Label):

    box_color = ListProperty(kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex("56b669"))
    prv_color = ListProperty(kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex("56b669"))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.always_release = True

    def on_press(self):
        self.prv_color = self.box_color
        self.box_color = (0,0,0,1)

    def on_release(self):
        self.box_color = self.prv_color


class KivMobDemo(App):

    def build(self):
        APP_ID = "ca-app-pub-ENTER#"
        BANNER_ID = "ca-app-pub-ENTER#"
        TEST_DEVICE_ID = "ca-app-pub-ENTER#"

        self.ads = KivMob(APP_ID)
        self.ads.add_test_device(TEST_DEVICE_ID)
        self.ads.new_banner({"unitID": BANNER_ID})
        self.ads.show_banner()
        self.ads.request_banner()
        self.toggled = False
        return KivMobDemoUI()

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        return True

    def toggle_banner(self):
        if not self.toggled:
            self.ads.show_banner()
        else:
            self.ads.hide_banner()
        self.toggled = not self.toggled

if __name__ == "__main__":
    KivMobDemo().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some notes in your buildozer.spec file:

```
requirements = kivy, android, jnius, kivmob
...
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.api = 27
android.minapi = 21
android.sdk = 24
android.ndk = 17b
android.gradle_dependencies = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
p4a.branch = master
android.meta_data = com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
```